# Time synchronization issues for kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, ntp

I`ve gotten delay time clock for some cluster nodes. Do I need to change the timesyncd service or any other thing to avoid synchronization issues?

Answer (score 1):

Time synchronization is very important because if on of node stay behind it may cause of "split brain".

Comment: I`m sure is very important, but how is the best way to certify the time synchronization?

Comment: Just configure any  NTP service on all nodes.